# Directline Webchat html code store values not coming to onmessage or onmember added

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, direct-line-botframework

We are trying to implement the Webchat and add some extra values like IP address, browser details etc.

Adding these values using

```
if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY') {
            dispatch({
                type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
                payload: {
                    name: 'start-chat',
                    value: {
                        "browser": Browser,
                        "ipAddress": ipAddress,
                        "location": Location,
                        "phoneNumber":sessiondata.phone_number
                    }
                }
            });
        }
these values are coming in request and context.activity also

{
  type: 'event',
  id: '**********',
  timestamp: 2022-09-13T11:37:27.491Z,
  localTimestamp: 2022-09-13T11:37:27.282Z,
  localTimezone: 'Asia/Calcutta',
  serviceUrl: 'https://directline.botframework.com/',
  channelId: 'directline',
  from: { id: '******', name: 'name', role: 'user' },
  conversation: { id: '********' },
  recipient: { id: '*******', name: '******' },
  locale: 'en-US',
  entities: [
    {
      type: 'ClientCapabilities',
      requiresBotState: true,
      supportsListening: true,
      supportsTts: true
    }
  ],
  channelData: {
    clientActivityID: '*******',
    clientTimestamp: '2022-09-13T11:37:27.282Z'
  },
  value: {
    browser: 'Chrome',
    ipAddress: '*******',
    location: 'Payyanur,Kerala,India',
    phoneNumber: '11111'
  },
  name: 'start-chat'
}
```

but these values are not coming to onmemberadded or onmessage context. Can someone help on this?

What are the possible values on the action.type like 'DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are posting an activity using the 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT' type which means the activity received by the bot will be of an `event` type.

To capture the incoming `event` activity, you need to configure you bot with the [onEvent()](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/main/libraries/botbuilder-core/src/activityHandler.ts#L246) activity handler.

```js
this.onEvent(async (context, next) => {
  console.log('Event activity detected');

  // do stuff

  await next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a type that will return "conversationupdate" or "message" type in the activity?

Comment: Did you follow the link I provided? You can see there all the activity handlers available, including `onConversationUpdate` and `onMessage`. FYI, there is also `onMembersAdded` which looks for the `membersAdded` property in an activity. However, `membersAdded` is NOT an activity type. It is generated  as a `conversationUpdate` activity. So, if you are watching both activity handlers, you will see it pass thru each.